# jquery: progress indicator failing to display / hide properly with ajax calls

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I have an html page with different sections on it (accomplished via DIV tags). 
These sections are created / updated using ajax calls.  One of the divs is actually a progress indicator - it just displays an image that tells the user that I'm processing their request in the background.

My problem is that this progress indicator is not always displayed when requested, even though the first few lines of code in each on click event hander has code to display this section. 
(and then at the end of each button click I hide the div)

here's a basic skeleton of my code:

```
 <div class="row-fluid">        
  <div class="span12">

      <h2>Title for Page></h2>
          <table class="table table-bordered table-striped"  id="assignedRecords">
          <thead>
              <tr>                  
                  <th>ID</th>
                  <th>Name</th>
                  <th>Status</th>
                  <th>Voice</th>
                  <th>Jumbo</th>
                  <th>Mode</th>
                  <th>&nbsp;</th>
              </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>

              <?php foreach ($databaserecords as $record): ?>
                  <tr>          
                                        ...  code to create initial table
                                        <td><button class='btn deleteBtn'>Delete</button></td>
                </tr>
              <?php endforeach ?>

          </tbody>
          </table>

          <div id="progress-indicator">
                 <img src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/img/wip.gif"> Retrieving records...</img>
          </div>    

          <button class="btn" id="getlist">Get List of Available Objects</button>
  </div>

  <div class="span12" id="availableObjectsAjaxContainer"></div> 
  <!--this is updated via ajax when the user clicks on the modify button. -->

 </div>   


  <script>

   $(document).ready(function(){

    //hide the please wait div by default.
    $('#progress-indicator').hide();


            $('#getlist').live('click', function()  {


                    $('#progress-indicator').html("<img src='" + BASEPATH + "assets/img/wip.gif' /> Retrieving...</img>");
                    $('#progress-indicator').fadeIn();      
                    .
                   // updates availableObjectsAjaxContainer section
                    .
                    .

    $('#deleteRecord').live('click', function()  {

                $('#progress-indicator').html("<img src='" + BASEPATH + "assets/img/wip.gif' /> deleting record...</img>");
                $('#progress-indicator').fadeIn();      
                .
                .
                // updates assignedRecords table section
                .
```

When the "getlist" button is clicked, it does display.  However, when the "deleteRecord" button is clicked, it is not displayed. 
I've made sure that my ajax calls do not accidentally "wipe out" the div that has the progress indicator.  My ajax calls only update the "assignedRecords" table section... and the "availableObjectsAjaxContainer" section.

Can you tell me where I'm going wrong?

Thanks.

**EDIT 1**

Here's what the full blown version of the deleteRecord click event handler function looks like:

```
  $('.deleteBtn').live('click', function()  {
                $('#progress-indicator').html("<img src='" + BASEPATH + "assets/img/wip.gif' /> deleting vlan...</img>");
                $('#progress-indicator').fadeIn();          
                //get a count of all records. only allowed to delete if you have more than one record.

                var reccount = $('#assignedRecords tbody tr').length;

                if (reccount > 1)
                {

                        var userSelectionId  = $(this).parent().siblings('.id').text(); 
                        var modeDelete = $(this).parent().siblings('.mode').text();


                        var fullpath = BASEPATH + 'index.php/switches/delete/' + userSelectionId + '/' + modeDelete;
                        console.log(fullpath);
                        $.ajax({
                                url:fullpath,
                                type:'POST',
                                dataType:'json',
                                success: function(returnDataFromController) {

                                                console.log(returnDataFromController);
                                                //build table contents 
                                                var htmlstring = '<thead>';  
                                                htmlstring = htmlstring + '<tr>';
                                                htmlstring = htmlstring + '<th>Id</th>';
                                                htmlstring = htmlstring + '<th>Name</th>';
                                                htmlstring = htmlstring + '<th>Status</th>';
                                                htmlstring = htmlstring + '<th>Voice</th>';
                                                htmlstring = htmlstring + '<th>Jumbo</th>';
                                                htmlstring = htmlstring + '<th>Mode</th>';
                                                htmlstring = htmlstring + '<th>&nbsp;</th>';
                                                htmlstring = htmlstring + '</tr>';
                                                htmlstring = htmlstring + '</thead>';
                                                htmlstring = htmlstring + '<tbody>';

                                                //loop through results from ajax call and build table.  
                                                for(i = 0; i < returnDataFromController.length; i++) {
                                                      //alert(returnDataFromController[i].Id);
                                                      htmlstring = htmlstring + "<tr>"
                                                      htmlstring = htmlstring + "<td class ='recordid'>" + returnDataFromController[i].Id + "</td>";
                                                      htmlstring = htmlstring + "<td>" + returnDataFromController[i].Name + "</td>";
                                                      htmlstring = htmlstring + "<td>" + returnDataFromController[i].Status + "</td>";
                                                      htmlstring = htmlstring + "<td>" + returnDataFromController[i].Voice +"</td>";
                                                      htmlstring = htmlstring + "<td>" + returnDataFromController[i].Jumbo + "</td>";
                                                      htmlstring = htmlstring + "<td class='mode'>" + returnDataFromController[i].Mode +"</td>";
                                                      htmlstring = htmlstring + "<td><button class='btn deleteBtn'>Delete</button></td>";
                                                      htmlstring = htmlstring + "</tr>";    

                                                }//end loop

                                               htmlstring = htmlstring + "</tbody>";
                                               htmlstring = htmlstring + "</table>";

                                             $('#assignedRecords').html(htmlstring);
                                  }//end success ajax call

                        });//end ajax.                                               
                }
                else
                {   
                    alert("Must have at least one record!");
                }
                $('#progress-indicator').hide();

  }); //end click event
```

**EDIT 2:**

```
    $('#getList').click(function()  {

            $(this).attr("disabled","disabled");
            $('#progress-indicator').html("<img src='" + BASEPATH + "assets/img/wip.gif' /> Retrieving ...</img>");
            $('#progress-indicator').fadeIn();
            $.ajax({
              url:"<?php echo site_url('switches/showavailrecs/'.$ip.'/'.$hardwaremodel);?>",
              type:'POST',
              dataType:'json',
              success: function(returnDataFromController) {

                  var htmlstring;


                  htmlstring = htmlstring + "<th>Id</th><th>Name</th>";

                  //loop through results
                  for(i = 0; i < returnDataFromController.length; i++) {
                          //alert(returnDataFromController[i].Id);
                          htmlstring = htmlstring +  "<tr><td><a href=>"+returnDataFromController[i].Id+"</a></td><td>"+ returnDataFromController[i].Name+"</td></tr>"; 

                  }


                  $('#availableObjectsAjaxContainer').html(htmlstring);

                  $('#progress-indicator').hide();
                 }//end success
              }); //end ajax call
              $(this).removeAttr("disabled");
    });
```

**EDIT 3:**

I think I figured out what's going on - although i don't know why it's doing it.

I've moved all my .hide commands to reside inside the success section of my ajax calls... and now... they seem to be working. 
Can anyone explain why this would be the case?

Comment: Can you show how you hide the progress-indictator when you call your `click` functions?

Comment: hey there. i've updated my post to include the stuff you asked for.  check out the last line in the delete button's click event.  Check out EDIT 1

Comment: Can you see (using Firebug or something) if the element is still there and if it is visible (perhaps behind something else) or hidden? Your `#getList` click function would be useful as well. From what I can see so far this should work.

Comment: I just added the getlist details.  I'm going to modify it so that the hide command happens regardless of whether or not the ajax call was successful.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it is related to your problem, but ID's need to be unique and you have one `#deleteRecord` element per object.

You should change your code to something like:

```
<td><button class='btn delete'>Delete</button></td>

...

$('.delete').live('click', function()  {
```

**Edit:** So obvious in the end (based on your latest edit): You were showing the progress indicator and hiding it immediately while it just started to fade in...

Comment: hey there.  thanks for the suggestion.  I've implemented the change and the delete button still works... but it didn't solve my problem with the progress indicator being displayed.

Comment: @dot Does the rest of that function work (does the deletion take place)?